# Degree of Freedoms in a Node of a 3D Frame/Beam Element

Tags: structural-analysis, statics

I recently took a quiz for my Matrix Methods of Structural Analysis Class, in which I encountered the following MCQ. My answer of '6' was justified, in my opinion, by the size of the stiffness matrix for a general 3-D beam element, which is 12x12 (6 for each node).
I am pretty sure I am correct but I would like confirmation on whether to approach my instructor with this.

[image]

Comment: Why are you not sure of your answer? Have you checked your notes? If you are sure then contact your instructor - easy enough to correct a question.

Comment: I have gotten lazy during online classes, so no notes. Also he hasn't introduced 3D elements yet.

Answer (score 1):

Six seems to be the correct answer: 
3 translational DoFs $\left(u_x\right.$, $u_y$, $\left.u_z\right)$ and 3 rotational DoFs $\left(\phi_x\right.$, $\phi_y$, $\left.\phi_z\right)$

You can even have a 3D beam element with [7 degrees of freedom](https://www.code-aster.org/V2/doc/v11/en/man_r/r3/r3.08.04.pdf). The 7th is for warping